# Configuração mascara monetária php

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e tenho valores inteiros, e no caso preciso converter 95686448 para (0,96) centavos porém usando o number_format() tenho um retorno 95.686.448,00 como configuro corretamente o number_format() para ter o retorno desejado ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o número a ser convertido tiver sempre a mesma quantidade de algarismos, basta o dividir pelo número que represente R$ 1,00 (no seu caso 100.000.000)

```
<?= number_format( 95686448/100000000,2,',','.') ?> //retorna 0,96
<?= number_format(  9568644/100000000,2,',','.') ?> //retorna 0,01
<?= number_format(956864488/100000000,2,',','.') ?> //retorna 9,57
```

Se não souber quantos algarismo terá o número mas sempre obtiver dezenas de centavos, basta adicionar a string '0.' no início

```
<?= number_format('0.'. '95686448'/100000000,2,',','.') ?> //retorna 0,96
<?= number_format('0.'.  '9568644'/100000000,2,',','.') ?> //retorna 0,96
<?= number_format('0.'.'956864488'/100000000,2,',','.') ?> //retorna 0,96
```